# Is there a good place to sleep/wait 9 hours in Nairobi Airport?

Tags: airports, layovers, sleeping, nbo

It appears that I will need to leave the secure area in NBO to collect my bags and re-check for my next flight, which is early the next morning.

Is there a safe/quiet place in the general airport (not past security) area that I can wait/sleep in NBO?

Comment: Have you checked out [Sleeping in Airports](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/africa/nairobi-airport.htm).. I clicked on Nairobi; it does includes reviews.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Deleted my comment.

Comment: @Giorgio I just checked.  Not really much there.  I am hoping for any firsthand info that people might have.

Comment: 9 hours is long. Accommodation close to the airport starts at around 15 euros. I'd consider that.

Comment: The site seems to have a good rep, and the absence of feedback may be an indicator that the hotel might be safest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First-hand experience, but several years out of date:

Nairobi Airport in general was safe.  There was a strong security presence and initial security checks are actually conducted at the entrances to the airport itself, prior to check-in.

I don't recall the general airport area being particularly quiet, or welcoming, or any of it being particularly comfortable.  We had to spend several hours there and it's a functional but old airport - quiet once you're past the post-checkin security checks, but not somewhere I reminisce on fondly.

Unless I was trying to save every penny, I'd get accommodation elsewhere (if trying to sleep) or set up camp in a hotel bar or cafe (if just wanting to rest). It's only about USD 20 to get a taxi into the city, with Uber being half to a quarter of that price.

Comment: I just found out we traveled prior to a reconstruction.  The new international check-in area looks nicer and more modern but I suspect the rest of the experience will be similar, just with new seats.

Comment: thanks for the answer. We’ll see how it all ends up in about 6 weeks. There are 16 if us travelling.

Comment: I think 16 might struggle to find space to set up shop all together, unless you happen to be travelling at quite a quiet time.

Comment: overnight.  From 8pm until about 6:00am